# Loop Group Options in the UK

Tags: crowd, adr, loop, group

Does anyone in the UK, or more specifically in the London area, know a crowd adr / loop group they'd recommend?  A lot of loop groups can be a bit hammy or o.t.t - I've yet to hear anyone rave about a group they use, so I thought I'd try SSD to see if I had a bit more luck.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: @Michael, wish I could help but loop groups are not my forté. Best of luck, though, and pls post if you've found a good one so that others can benefit.

Comment: Thanks Jay - will definitely post if I make any discoveries - don't know about in the States but over here there seems a real lack of an imaginative or creative solution to the issue that is more on a par with the attention to detail given to the other elements of the soundtrack.  And yet it's damn expensive!

Comment: @Micheal,it's definitely worth trying Vanessa at audiocatz. I've had some great stuff from her group in the past. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Vanessa & Bern - will definitely give you a shout next time I need a loop group.  Will report back with feedback when I do!

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

Let me introduce you to http://audiocatz.com for ADR Loop Group and Character Revoicing.

Any questions - just drop us an Email

Best wishes,

Vanessa Baker